# Transferring Result Data via HTTP Header? - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to upload file without refreshing the page.

I got 1 form, 1 submit, 1 file input and 1 iframe in order to prevent refreshing.

Form sending data via iframe, so my form have target attribute.

After my c# function's work, I want to return result data, such as message, issuccess etc.

I don't know how to return result data without using http header.

Maybe it's also not possible with http header. I don't know. I am here to learn how to do.

Transferring result data via http header makes sense? Is it preferable way?

Does it occurs vulnerability?

Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use Ajax for this?

Comment: If I use ajax, I have to generate my page using model, right? I don't want to use model, because I hate adding modelerror.

Comment: You can generate your page without a model if you wish.  However, there's no requirement to add ModelError just because you use a model with your view.  That is an optional pattern to be used where it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Typically it's hard to get a file over the wire without a form post.
What I've done often is use an invisible iframe for a form post and then have the iframe call a function in the parent page upon load. This assumes you can't just use jquery or a recent version of dojo to take care of this for you.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe/

If you can use jquery it's much nicer. Edit: this is under the mit license
http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Using it in official projects is legal? Can I use it in every project?

Comment: Yes jquery is free for commercial use. so is dojo. They both can take care of this for you. Most big sites are using jquery for ui.

Comment: I am not talking about jquery, I am talking about jquery file uploader at here: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes This is under the MIT license: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Answer (score 0):

Why not take advantage of the HTML5 File API.  These links should point you in the right direction.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

http://timothypoon.com/blog/2011/05/10/ajax-uploading-with-html5s-file-api/

Comment: What if user doesn't have html 5 supported browser?